# Implementing AI pointer error

Tags: c

For my uni project I'm trying to create a basic tank game in `C`, but I've only just started learning `C` and have a very basic understanding of `C`. So I've started working on some simple code for a AI player, but when I compile it with `GNU GCC` compiler it comes up with these errors and I've got no clue how to proceed. So help would be great please! :D

> Line 41 warning: passing argument 3 of 'AIMove' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
>
> Line 19 note: expected 'int (*)()' but argument is of type 'int'

```
int PosCheck(int T1Pos, int T2Pos)
{
   int a;

   a = T2Pos - T1Pos;

   if(a == 0) // Stop the tanks trying to overlay
   {
      return 0;
   }

   if(a >= 1 || a < 0) // Allows the tanks to move foward
   {
      return 1;
   }
}

int AIMove(int T1Pos, int T2Pos, int PosCheck()) // AI movement
{
   int b, c;

   if(PosCheck(T1Pos, T2Pos) == 0) // Choose retreat options or stands still
   {
      b = 3 + round(3*(int)rand()/(int)RAND_MAX);
      return b;
   }
   if(PosCheck(T1Pos, T2Pos) == 1) // Chooses foward options
   {
      c = 1 + round(3*(int)rand()/(int)RAND_MAX);;
      return c;
   }
}

main()
{
   int T1Pos;
   int T2Pos;
   int T2MC;

   T2MC = AIMove(T1Pos, T2Pos, PosCheck(T1Pos, T2Pos));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This function takes another function as a parameter because of these parens:

```
int AIMove(int T1Pos, int T2Pos, int PosCheck()) // AI movement
                                             ^^
```

But when you call it, you are passing the result of a same-named function:

```
T2MC = AIMove(T1Pos, T2Pos, PosCheck(T1Pos, T2Pos));
```

What is the `PosCheck` parameter supposed to do? Inside `AIMove` you call it, but it's not clear if you want the global `PosCheck` function or the argument.

By the way, the usual way to declare a function pointer is with an asterisk:

```
int AIMove(int T1Pos, int T2Pos, int (*PosCheck)()) // Obviously a pointer.
```

If there's nothing in particular you are trying to accomplish there, just delete the parameter and the argument.

```
T2MC = AIMove(T1Pos, T2Pos);

int AIMove(int T1Pos, int T2Pos)
```